# Why when using seq -s delimiter is after the last element?

Tags: macos, seq

I was trying different examples from Unix shell tutorial with `seq` command and got a different result in my terminal.

command:

```
seq -s '/' 1 5
```

result:

```
1/2/3/4/5/
```

instead of

```
1/2/3/4/5
```

The command works as expected in online `bash`, only mine does it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the non-standard utility `seq` found installed by default on macOS is not the same as found in the coreutils package on GNU systems.  The macOS `seq` utility is inherited [from FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=seq&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html).

On macOS, the string used as the option-argument to the `-s` option of `seq` is  replacing the default newline character ordinarily used for this purpose. This means every number is followed by the string used with `-s`, including the last number.  To insert a newline at the end, you may use `-t '\n'` (the `-t` option is not available with GNU `seq`).  Note that this still adds the `-s` delimiter after the last number:

```
$ seq -s '-->' -t '[end of list]\n' 1 3
1-->2-->3-->[end of list]
```

With the coreutils `seq` implementation, the string used with `-s` is used to delimit the numbers, but the last element is always terminated by a newline character.

This difference in the two `seq` implementations is probably due to developer preferences and/or need, but that's just me speculating.

On macOS, you may install coreutils using Homebrew, and access GNU `seq` as `gseq`.